# How to access uart from linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write simple kernel module that uses a device connected to the system via serial line, but I'm having trouble actually accessing the UART. I think I know how to communicate with the device with `kernel_read` and `kernel_write`:

```
struct file* serial_file;
char buf[32];
lsoff_t off = 0;
serial_file = filp_open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR, 0);
kernel_write(serial_file, "test\n", 5, &off);
kernel_read(serial_file, buf, 32, &off);
```

The file seems to be open (`IS_ERR(serial_file)` is 0), but reads and writes return EIO - probably because of the wrong baudrate. Since there is no kernel_ioctl, there's no obvious way to fix this.

Answer to the problem above would be nice, but since this is more of a hack (from my understanding filesystem shouldn't really be accessed from kernel in this fashion), even nicer would be explanation how to do this properly? I'd guess it would involve calling functions from `tty_struct` directly, but how to get it from `file` (or from path, or from whatever it should be generated from)?

Comment: No, no, just no. No files for UART, please! You have to provide proper ACPI or Device Tree excerpt and driver of the device should find proper UART to communicate through.

Comment: How do I get ACPI/device tree info? And from this, how do I get to communication with the device? Please forgive my illiteracy in the matter, my knowledge of kernel ends on basics of character device drivers.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but right now I'm using UML for testing.

Comment: I don't know about ACPI, but systems that use device trees can add a child device node in a uart device node, with a `compatible = "something,something";` property to be matched to a driver. Such drivers should be "serial bus device" drivers. An example of such a driver is "drivers/gnss/sirf.c" and an example device tree fragment can be found in "arch/arm/boot/dts/omap3-gta04.dtsi" in the `gnss` node with `compatible = "wi2wi,w2sg0004";` OF device ID that is matched by the driver.